# How to run Perl script in tomcat server using RewriteMap

Tags: perl, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I want to call Perl script in rewrite.config which I have placed in `webapps/myapplication/WebContent/WEB-INF`
What steps should I take in order to use `RewriteMap`

Answer (score 2):

Check the below sections to be enabled in your WEB-INF\web.xml

**Step 1:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**Step 2**

```
<!-- The mapping for the CGI Gateway servlet -->


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cgi-bin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```